# Comparing logistic regression in Scikit-learn (Python) and glm (R)

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, glm

I am trying to compare logistic regression in R glm stats package and Scikit-learn Python. Here is my dataset. [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xC2UfhkMZQceDPnZir4BuvHcWQICIf1/view?usp=sharing).

Here is python code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['var2'], prefix = 'var2', drop_first= True))
df.drop(columns = ['var2'], inplace = True)

X = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'y']
y = df.y

model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, penalty = 'none' )
model.fit(X, y)
prob = model.predict_proba(X)
model.coef_
```

Here are the coefficients:

```
var1, var3, var4, var2_B, var2_C
-1.833653e-07, 2.823982e-12, 2.568188e-12, -4.116901e-13, 5.514602e-14
```

And here is corresponding R code:

```
df=read_csv(file = "dataset.csv")
glm_fit <- glm(y ~.,data = df,   family=binomial(link = 'logit'))
summary(glm_fit)
```

Here are coefficients:

```
(Intercept) -6.459e-01 
var1        -1.042e-07  
var2B       -7.731e-01  
var2C        1.880e+00  
var3        -1.124e-04  
var4         2.994e-03
```

It is easy to check that matrix that goes into solver is the same in both case.
As you can see, coefficients are drastically different. Also ROC AUC in R comes up way better than in Python. I understand that different solvers are used, but difference in solution seems too big. Is there way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I'll have a closer look later, but I suspect it's an issue of scaling and convergence. IIRC R scales internally and then adjusts coefficients back; whereas sklearn leaves it up to you, and the solver may do a bad job on unscaled data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it seems to be a matter of the `lbfgs` solver (the default used by `sklearn`) failing to work well on unscaled input data.  Scaling the inputs first and modifying the coefficients accordingly, I recover basically the same coefficients you reported from `glm`:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_sc = scaler.fit_transform(X)
model.fit(X_sc, y)
model.coef_ / scaler.scale_
```

The `sag` and `saga` solvers suffer the same fate, while `newton-cg` actually gets close and throws convergence warnings.  Increasing the number of iterations just adds a warning about rounding errors preventing better convergence.